# HTML Comments Clarification

Tags: html, tags, comments

Can I use /* */ comment tags in html .

If not why because they are common for comments ?

Comment: _they are universal for comments_ [citation needed]

Comment: They are **not** universal for comments. They are normally used in C like languages (C#, Java, Javascript, C++ and C are all examples of such). VB.NET, VB, Haskell, Ruby and others have different notation for comments.

Comment: I don't think they're 'universal for comments', it just so happens a lot of languages implement their comments in the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot. You can use `<!-- -->`

As to the second part of the question, <strike>I can't really help you there :)</strike>

EDIT - Just realized that /* */ wouldn't be tags at all, which would make sense as to why you can't use them,

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, because the [specification says so](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4):

> HTML comments have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> <!-- this is a comment --> <!-- and so is this one,
>     which occupies more than one line -->
> ```
>
> White space is not permitted between the markup declaration open
>   delimiter(""). A common error is to include a
>   string of hyphens ("---") within a comment. Authors should avoid
>   putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.
>
> Information that appears between comments has no special meaning
>   (e.g., character references are not interpreted as such).
>
> Note that comments are markup.

That last line tells you why you can't use /* */ - because HTML comments are markup too, just like any other tag, and those "universal comments" would not be tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
<!-- A Comment -->
```

in HTMl as far as I'm aware.

/*

*/

is not universal, although it is common for block comments